# [Vue warn]: Unhandled error during execution of setup function

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js, vuejs3, nuxtjs3

`[Vue warn]: Unhandled error during execution of setup function <[...slug] onVnodeUnmounted=fn<onVnodeUnmounted> ref=Ref< undefined > >`

This error comes up all the time without any obvious cause, while I'm developing with Nuxt 3 (Vue 3). I assume it's happening whenever Nuxt is processing request to an external API but I don't know.

It's mostly fine, just the error in the local/Terminal console (not in the browser). But sometimes, it breaks the site with a cryptic "DOM exception, user aborted the request" type message.

This happens rarely on the live site but does sometimes and it's bothersome.

Anyone know what might be causing it? Anyone experiencing similar?

Nothing is obvious to me to try, it's quite cryptic.

Comment: It's not exactly cryptic. One (or more) of your `setup` functions are **not handling** errors. Most likely, you're making HTTP requests and you only coded in the success clause. Ideally, you should also tell the browser (through your app) how to handle any errors on those requests. I'm guessing you use `axios`. Adding a `.catch(() => void 0)` to your requests will make the warning go away.

Comment: It can also happen when you don't abort pending requests initiated by the component upon unmounting the component. It's not a big problem, *per-se*. More of a testimony to the argument that separation of concerns matters in frontend development.

Comment: @tao your point sounds like what I should look into. I wish it would be much clearer what in particular is causing it to error though. I'm not using `axios` but I'll sure look and double-sure I'm terminating all requests with error-handling. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

"It might be a good idea to check whether the Vue lifetime hook has been added to the component code.
like Import { onMounted } from 'vue'."

Or is the added library properly included under the script tag in the component?